# Elegant way to position two rectangles

Tags: javascript, ruby, math, language-agnostic, coordinates

I have a rectangle (called the **target**) and want to place another rectangle (called the **satellite**) alongside. The satellite has a **position** (top, bottom, left, right) that determines the placement edge relative to the target. It also has an **alignment**  that (left, center, right for top and bottom position, top, middle and bottom for left and right position).

Example:

```
+----------+----------------------------+
|          |                            |
|  Target  | Satellite, Position=RIGHT, |
|          | Align=TOP                  |
|          |                            |
|          |----------------------------+
|          |
+----------+
```

I know the **top left coordinates** of the target and also its **width and height**. I also know the width and height of the satellite and want to calculate the top left coordinates of it. I could do that as a series of 12 `if` clauses, but maybe there is a more elegant, mathematical or algorithmic way to do it. Is there an alternative way to this:

```
# s = satellite, t = target
if pos == "top" && align == "left"
  s.x = t.x
  s.y = t.y - s.height
else if pos == "top" && align == "center"
  s.x = t.x + t.width / 2 - s.width / 2
  s.y = t.y - s.height
# etc, etc
```

Any good solutions in Ruby or JavaScript?

Comment: Dude, nice text diagram! Did you use any special tool to generate it?

Comment: Yes, I used JavE, a specialized ASCII diagram editor: http://www.jave.de/

Comment: man why don't you put `language-agnostic` tag???

Comment: I dind't know it existed ;-) Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

I like the other answer, but here's how to do it without having to store anything.  All math and logic using the trick that in javascript `true` evaluates to 1 and `false` evaluates to 0 when arithmetic operators are applied:

p.s. (check out the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vQqSe/52/)

```
var t = {
    jq: $('#target'),
    width: parseInt($('#target').css('width')),
    height: parseInt($('#target').css('height')),
    top: parseInt($('#target').css('top')),
    left: parseInt($('#target').css('left'))
};
var s = {
    jq: $('#satellite'),
    width: parseInt($('#satellite').css('width')),
    height: parseInt($('#satellite').css('height'))
};

// start with it top left and add using javascript tricks
s.jq.css('top', t.top - s.height +
    s.height * (a == 'top') +
    (t.height/2 + s.height/2) * (a == 'middle') +
    t.height * (a == 'bottom') +
    (t.height + s.height) * (p == 'bottom')
);        

s.jq.css('left', t.left - s.width +
    t.width * (a == 'left') +
    s.width * (a == 'right') +
    (s.width/2 + t.width/2) * (a == 'center') +
    (s.width + t.width) * (p == 'right')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used a series of objects it will do the trick:

```
var positions = {

    top: {left:{x:t.x, y:y.y-s.height}, center:{x:tx.x + t.width/2- s.width/2, y:t.y-s.height}}
    //etc....
}
//then to get the position you can simply
var pos = positions[pos][align])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def vector pos, align, hash
  case hash[pos]
  when -1;     [0.0, -1.0]
  when 1;      [1.0, 0.0]
  else
    case hash[align]
    when -1;   [0.0, 0.0]
    when 1;    [1.0, -1.0]
    else       [0.5, -0.5]
    end
  end
end

y_t, y_s = vector(pos, align, "top" => -1, "bottom" => 1)
x_t, x_s = vector(pos, align, "left" => -1, "right" => 1)
s.y = t.y + y_t*t.height + y_s*s.height
s.x = t.x + x_t*t.width + x_s*s.width
```

or

```
def vector pos, align, head, tail
  case pos
  when head;   [0.0, -1.0]
  when tail;   [1.0, 0.0]
  else
    case align
    when head; [0.0, 0.0]
    when tail; [1.0, -1.0]
    else       [0.5, -0.5]
    end
  end
end

y_t, y_s = vector(pos, align, "top", "bottom")
x_t, x_s = vector(pos, align, "left", "right")
s.y = t.y + y_t*t.height + y_s*s.height
s.x = t.x + x_t*t.width + x_s*s.width
```